# Anderson localization for non-i.i.d. potentials

Tags: sp.spectral-theory

Consider a random potential $V$ on edges of $\mathbb{Z}$ defined in the following way:

a) each edge starts with an i.i.d. $0$ or $1$

b) each edge chooses its new potential value according to some predetermined function $f$ of its neighborhood of diameter $l$, $F: \{0,1\}^l \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (same function for each vertex)

In other words, $V$ arises as a "factor of i.i.d." (obtained from i.i.d. by a rule depending on bounded neighborhoods)

Are there any techniques for proving Anderson localization for this class of potentials? (e.g. of the form - if an i.i.d. potential of some type exhibits localization, then a factor of i.i.d. potential does so as well)